# Yii2 required validation on update

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I've Yii2 form containing form fields depending on action of page. Ex. Few fields appears when then action is `create` and few appears when action is `update`. I want to add required validation based on this scenario.

Ex.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'unique_identifier')->textInput(['maxlength' => 45]) ?>
```

I am showing this field only when `action => 'update'`.

Now I want to add required validation for this and I tried this:

```
[['unique_identifier'], 'required', 'on' => 'update'],
```

But above validation not working. If I remove `on=>update` then its validating on both create and update scenario.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: afaik this should be ok... I'll star this question, I'm curious...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*ActiveRecord* does not set scenario automaticaly when you update or create items. You must override `update()` method in your model and set scenario that you need. E.g. in your case

```
public function update($runValidation = true, $attributeNames = null)
{
    $this->scenario = 'update';
    return parent::update($runValidation, $attributeNames);
}
```

Also you can set scenario in your `actionUpdate`

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->scenario = 'update';
    //load data from request, save model etc.
 }
```